# Set up bluetooth keyboard to enter disk encryption password

Tags: boot, keyboard, startup, bluetooth, disk-encryption

How can I set up a bluetooth keyboard, so that I can use it to enter the disk encryption key, so that my encrypted linux system boots.

Comment: Does the bluetooth signal need to be encrypted?

Comment: As of 2020, I don't think we have the technology to (easily) do this yet. You need to get a wireless keyboard that comes with its own USB dongle.